# What rims are these?

Tags: part-identification, wheels

I'm not sure if I'm in the right place for asking this question, but maybe someone knows offhand.

This is my Acura TL 2004, and it has these custom rims on it. One rim is bent a bit and it's causing my car to drift to the right pretty hard, so I need a replacement rim. How can I find an identical rim? Does anyone know what they are called, or better yet, does anyone know where I can go to find out? Is it written on the rim somewhere? (I looked, but didn't find anything. Also, I am kind of lazy, so I haven't taken the rims off yet to look behind.)

[image: Front left rim]

I appreciate any advice you can give!

[image]

Comment: I don't recognize them, but I have heard there are companies that specialize in straightening alloy wheels.

Comment: A bent rim shouldn't cause a drifting issue, but rather you'd feel the rhythmic vibration as the defect rolls across the surface of the road. Why do you believe it's a bent rim? How is it bent? If your car is drifting, this leads me to believe there's another issue at play here ... quite possibly damaged or worn suspension parts.

Comment: There may be casting marks that indicate the size/manufacture on the INSIDE of the rim; you'd have to take the tire off.  But Paulster is right -- a bent rim won't cause a pull.  More likely whatever incident that bent the rim also affected camber or caster - the only alignment factors that can create a pull.   Toe changes do not create a pull!

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, I had my mechanic redo the alignment on the vehicle and he said the camber and caster are perfectly aligned. I'm not exactly sure how it's causing the pull, but that what he said. I appreciate the advice, guys!